# Ceiling fan only runs when bare used as hot

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

So I'm trying to wire up my new ceiling fan. I connected the black and blue to the black from ceiling and the white to white and the green from the braces to the bare wire.

However, nothing came on.

I got bored and curious so I connected the blue wire to the bare wire and when I flipped on my breakers, everything worked. That is except the pull chain for the light turns off both the light and fan. And the pull chain for the fan slows the rotation and dims the light.

I know this isn't safe, and I have no intentions of keeping it this way.

My question is do I have faulty wiring in my house, or is the fan faulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have a ground or neutral that's hot. This is very dangerous and you need to call a professional electrician before someone gets electrocuted.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the grammar issues, it's hard to type this on my phone.